# Remove weekend gaps in gnuplot for candlestick chart

Tags: gnuplot, candlestick-chart

I am trying to plot some financial candlestick charts with gnuplot. The problem is that there is no data during the weekends, and I don't want these gaps to be showed. Picture and code included below.

```
set datafile separator ","
set xdata time
set timefmt"%Y-%m-%d"
set xrange ["2015-10-22":"2016-02-06"]
set yrange [*:*]
set format x
plot 'head.dat' using 1:2:4:3:5 notitle with candlesticks
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data that elicits the problem.

Comment: Sorry, of course. Uploaded it here: http://textuploader.com/5n9gd @Thor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you have one entry per working day, instead of using the dates as abscissae you can use the line number:

```
plot 'head.dat' using 0:2:4:3:5 notitle with candlesticks
```

Then I guess you'll ask how to restore the dates on the `x`-axis. You can use `xticslabel` :

```
set xtics rotate 90
plot "head.dat" u 0:2:4:3:5:xticlabels(1) notitle with candlesticks
```

If you want to avoid having every label shown use this `everyNth` function [posted by *dir*](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.graphics.apps.gnuplot/M_ldKLSFXwg/FFeOPZ4MCccJ), e.g. every fifth label:

```
set datafile separator ","
everyNth(countColumn, labelColumnNum, N) = \
  ( (int(column(countColumn)) % N == 0) ? stringcolumn(labelColumnNum) : "" ) 
set xtics rotate 90
plot "head.dat" using 0:2:4:3:5:xticlabels(everyNth(0, 1, 5)) notitle with candlesticks
```

Results in:

[image: Candlestick graph with no weekend gaps]

Comment: Nice +1. The second solution produces one label for each data point, this can be reduced by using [the every Nth function](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.graphics.apps.gnuplot/M_ldKLSFXwg/FFeOPZ4MCccJ).

Comment: Well, that's a clean solution. Combined it with the every Nth function and it turned out perfect. Thanks @Joce and @Thor!

Comment: Thanks @Thor, that's a great improvement!